# mysql date_format() or str_to_date() in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I've view named Sales View

```
select * from SalesView;
```

[image]

I want to fetch records from SalesView having order_date 9-OCT-2019.
Value for Order date is supplied from GUI in format DD-MM-YYYY.

I tried,

```
select * 
from salesView 
where str_to_date(order_date,'%d-%m-%Y') = str_to_date('09-10-2019','%d-%m-%Y')
order by oID;
```

[image]

I've also tried date_format() instead of str_to_date(), but It is returning nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your where clause

```
where str_to_date(order_date,'%d-%m-%Y') = str_to_date('09-10-2019','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Replace order_date's format with the format in which database stored it. **YYYY-MM-DD**

```
where str_to_date(order_date,'%Y-%m-%d') = str_to_date('09-10-2019','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: In oracle I used to do
" select * from TBL where to_date(order_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = to_date('DD-MM-YYYY');" __

It was working in Oracle. But I didn't know that we have to replace column's format with database date format in case of mysql.

Thanks.

Comment: Not that much interacted with Oracle. BUT there should not be like that you are claiming .. just read http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date

Comment: I developed several projects using same idea. 
If we want to compare string provided from textbox with string in database then I convert column_name and value in same format. eg. upper or lower case.

"select * from TBL where upper(column_name) = upper(value_by_user)";

Similarly, in oracle, I used to convert both the column_value and value_by_user in common date format. It still works fine on oracle database.

Comment: Wrapping `order_date` in a function is going to prevent MySQL from using a range  scan to satisfy that predicate. If `order_date` is datatype DATE, then we can just do `where order_date =` . Same is true if `order_date` is canonical string format, always formatted as four digit year, dash, two digit month. Using the STR_TO_DATE function wrapper would have the benefit of handling some variances in the string format, using slashes as separators, or single digit month, converting string values like  '2019-9-30'  or `2019/10/1' into DATE datatype.